# LibGDX How to set spacing between list items in a Scene 2D Select Box Widget?

Tags: java, libgdx, gui, scene2d

I have created a [Select Box (Scene2D widget)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/SelectBox.html) which holds a list of items, to be selected. My code works fine, but I would like to make a little more spacing between each list item in the dropdown list in the select box. How can I achieve that??

My code for the list box is this.

```
List.ListStyle selectBoxListStyle = new List.ListStyle();
selectBoxListStyle.background = new NinePatchDrawable(new NinePatch(this.selectBoxListBackgroundTexture, 10, 10, 10, 10));
selectBoxListStyle.font = this.textFieldFont;
selectBoxListStyle.fontColorSelected = Color.WHITE;
selectBoxListStyle.fontColorUnselected = Color.BROWN;
selectBoxListStyle.selection = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(this.textFieldSelectionTexture));

SelectBox.SelectBoxStyle selectBoxStyle = new SelectBox.SelectBoxStyle();
selectBoxStyle.background = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(this.selectBoxMiddleBackgroundTexture));
selectBoxStyle.backgroundOpen = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(this.selectBoxMiddleActiveBackgroundTexture));
selectBoxStyle.font = this.textFieldFont;
selectBoxStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
selectBoxStyle.listStyle = selectBoxListStyle;
selectBoxStyle.scrollStyle = new ScrollPane.ScrollPaneStyle();

SelectBox<String> selectBoxWidget = new SelectBox(selectBoxStyle);
selectBoxWidget.setItems("Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3");
```

Comment: Use padding. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
selectBoxStyle.listStyle.selection.setTopHeight(10);
```